# MeteorJs toggle template's reactivity [auto-update] on client-side?

Tags: meteor

Is there a good method to toggle template's reactivity on client-side by checkbox?

---

### Client Main HTML

```
<section class="margin-bottom-10" id="trend">
        <div class="headline">
            <h4><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i> section1</h4>
            <div class="checkbox auto-update-check">
                <label><input type="checkbox" id="Trend" checked="checked">auto-update</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <!--<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">-->
            {{> list1}}
        <!--</div>-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            {{> list2}}
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            {{> list3}}
    </div>
```

---

Main has 3 sections and checkboxes.

and I want to toggle the reactivity(auto-update) each section on client-side.

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mViem.png)

Comment: Reactivity on what data, obtained how, and used in which way in your template? Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] and a basis for answers.